# Which of the following statements are true for the elements in $\mathscr S\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

> Let $\mathscr S$ be the family of continuous real valued functions on $(0, \infty)$ defined by $$\mathscr S : = \left \{f : (0, \infty) \longrightarrow \Bbb R\ |\ f(x) = f(2x),\ \forall x \in (0, \infty) \right \}.$$ For each of the following statements, state whether it is true or false.
>
> $(a)$ Any element $f \in \mathscr S$ is bounded.
>
> $(b)$ Any element $f \in \mathscr S$ is uniformly continuous.
>
> $(c)$ Any element $f \in \mathscr S$ is differentiable.
>
> $(d)$ Any uniformly bounded sequence in $\mathscr S$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

I have proved that $(a)$ is true because for any $x \in (0,\infty)$ there exists $n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $2^n x \in [1,2].$ Since $[1,2]$ is compact it follows that for any $f \in \mathscr S$ there exists $M_f \gt 0$ such that for all $y \in [1,2]$ we have $|f(y)| \leq M_f.$ But then by the given hypothesis $|f (x)| = |f(2^n x)| \leq M_f,$ as required.

But I have no idea about $(b), (c)$ and $(d).$ I think $(b)$ and $(c)$ are false. But I am unable to construct an element $f \in \mathscr S$ which will work as a counter-example. Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think that $f$ is constant on positive dyadic rationals if $f \in \mathscr S$ is uniformly continuous. Since the set of positive dyadic rationals is dense in $(0,\infty),$ $f$ will be a constant function. So if we can produce a non-constant function $f \in \mathscr S$ then $(b)$ is false.

Comment: $f$ belongs to this family iff $f(x)=g(\ln x)$ where $g$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ with period $\ln 2$. 

$f(x)=\sin (\frac {2\pi \ln x} {\ln 2})$ is a function in this family which is not uniformly continuous since it has no limit as $ x \to 0$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy similarly we could have taken $f(x) = \left \lvert \sin \left (\frac {2 \pi \ln x} {\ln 2} \right ) \right \rvert,\ x \in (0, \infty).$ Then $f \in \mathscr S$ but $f$ will not be differentiable at the points $1 + n \ln 2,$ for $n \geq 0.$ So both $(b)$ and $(c)$ are false. What about $d\ $?

Comment: What will happen if we take the sequence  of functions $\{f_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ defined by $$f_n(x) = \sin \left (\frac {2 \pi n \ln x} {\ln 2} \right ),\ x \in (0,\infty)?$$

Comment: That was my choice of $(f_n)$ too but I don't have a proof yet of the fact that it has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy for any $x \neq 1$ can $f_n$ even converge pointwise? We know that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sin n$ doesn't exist.

Comment: It does not converge pointwise. But the question  is whether there is a subsequence which converges.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ doesn't converge pointwise then how can there be any subsequence $\{f_{n_k} \}_{k \geq 1}$ of $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ which converges pointwise? I think similar argument will work because $n_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$ and hence the limit of $\sin n_k$ doesn't even exist as $k \to \infty.$